# Would the query optimizer be able to extract an effective constant from a WHERE clause to avoid repeated evaluation?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

Would I gain any performance benefit from rewriting a function that looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION some_text_predicate(name text) RETURNS boolean AS $$
    SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sc.foo
        WHERE foo.name = some_transform(name)
    );
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

as this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION some_text_predicate(text) RETURNS boolean AS $$
    DECLARE
        name text := some_transform($1);
    BEGIN
        RETURN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sc.foo
            WHERE foo.name = name
        );
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The rationale being that the result of `some_transform` is a constant and doesn't need to be reevaluated on each row that the `WHERE` clause executes. Is the query optimizer smart enough to extract this as a constant or must I use the second function definition for the benefit I seek?

I'm looking for details on the optimization of the evaluation of `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: If you mark `some_transform` as `STABLE` or `IMMUTABLE`, whichever suits better, it would be only evaluated once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on `some_transform` and the query.

If that function is `IMMUTABLE` (is guaranteed to return the same result for the same arguments) or `STABLE` (returns the same result for the same argument for the duration of the current query and does not modify the database), you can label your function the same.

Then the optimizer will know that the function only has to be evaluated once if the argument remains constant for the duration of the query.

An `IMMUTABLE` function will be evaluated when the query is planned, a `STABLE` function once at execution time.

That will help you with a query like

```
WHERE a.x = some_text_predicate('const')
```

but not with

```
WHERE some_text_predicate(a.x) = 'const'
```

I would prefer the first function if you can profit from that, because it is simpler.

If you cannot avoid the function being called often, the second function might be better, because PL/pgSQL functions cache execution plans. But you cannot avoid that the expensive function is called multiple times that way.

Comment: If the SQL function is declared `stable` or `immutable`  isn't it also a candidate for inlining which would be more efficient than the PL/pgSQL overhead?

Comment: Not if it contains a subquery.

Comment: Even if some_transform was immutable, I couldn’t mark some_text_predicate as immutable because its result depends on the contents of sc.foo, correct?

Comment: Right, it would be `STABLE`.